# No route matches error with application_controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an application_controller spec that is failing since I removed the controller/action route from routes.rb.  I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"application", :action=>"index"}
```

I had many tests fail in the same way, but was able to fix them by including the correct parameters in the get call.  So for instance, if I wanted to get the standard show route for posts in my spec, I had to change

```
get :show to get :show, :id => '1'
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure now what to pass along for the application controller specs.  I've included my test below.

```
describe ApplicationController do

  it "should find the latest published posts and assign them for the view" do
    Post.should_receive(:latest).and_return(@posts)
    get :index
    assigns[:posts].should == @posts
  end


  it "should find the latest approved comments and assign them for the view" do
    Comment.should_receive(:latest).and_return(@comments)
    get :index
    assigns[:comments].should == @comments
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the ApplicationController as an abstract class not intended to be used for requests. All new controllers generated will inherit from ApplicationController so it is a nice place to put shared behavior.